# How to edit directory structure in HEX in Windows?

Tags: filesystems, filesystem-corruption

I have some strange filesystem damage, where some files are treated as directories. Scandisk sees no problems.

So, I would like to edit/check directory in HEX as it was in ancient times with Norton Disk Editor.

Is it possible nowadays?

I don't need to see disc sectors in raw. I wan't to see parsed filesystem structures.

Comment: Are we talking about FAT32 or NTFS.

Comment: Any. Let it be FAT32, and if NTFS -- then better.